# Is there a way to filter ansible vars based on condition

Tags: ansible

I have this vars in the playbook and multiple tasks, I just want to filter the items from vars list based on the prompt input. Right now I have to exclude that item using when from multiple tasks. Please see following example:

```
vars_prompt:
    - name: rmetcd
      prompt: "remove etcd: YES OR NO?"
      private: no

vars:
    containers:
      - "etcd"
      - "mysql"
      - "postgres"

    folders:
      - "etcd"
      - "mysql"
      - "postgres"
tasks:
    - name: remove container
         shell: "docker rm -f {{ item }}"
         with_items: "{{ containers }}"
         when: 
           - '"etcd" not in item' 

    - name: remove folder
         file:
           path: "{{ item }}"
           state: absent
         with_items: "{{ folders }}"
         when: 
           - '"etcd" not in item' 

 when: rmetcd == "NO"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the problem in reverse order: rather than filtering my list for each task to potentially take out an element, I would define my list with default elements and add the additional one if user answered yes.

Note: your two lists are identical, I only kept one in the following example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:
    - name: rmetcd
      prompt: "Remove etcd [yes/no]?"
      private: no

  vars:
    _default_services:
      - mysql
      - postgres

    services: "{{ _default_services + (rmetcd | bool | ternary(['etcd'], [])) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: task1
      debug:
        msg: "remove container {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ services }}"

    - name: taks2
      debug:
        msg: "remove folder {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ services }}"
```

The key points:

- I defined a "private" variable `_default_services`. This is the list of services that will always be included.
- I calculated the variable `services` which is an addition of two lists: `_default_services` and the additional value to add depending on user input. For this last one:

  - I used `rmetcd` containing the value (which should be "yes" or "no")
  - I applied the [`bool` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) to cast the value to boolean
  - and I used the [`ternary` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) to select a single element list if true (`['etcd']`) and an empty list if false (`[]`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. If my container name is in jinja2 templating, how could I solve that and if I need to put multiple container names. For example:
`services: "{{ _default_services + (rmetcd | bool | ternary(['{{ network_id }}-mysql-{{ mysql_port }}'], [])) }}"`

Comment: `services: "{{ _default_services + (rmetcd | bool | ternary([network_id + '-mysql-' + mysql_port], [])) }}"`

Comment: I am getting this error:
`can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`
I think it cannot parse port number.

Comment: cast your int (i.e. `mysql_port`) to a string with the `string` filter